# how to automatically color a certain instance of text?

Tags: css, text, colors

I have made a website for a basketball association. It has a number of teams that each have their calendars. You can see it [here](http://www.storylinedesign.be/sites/modu/ploegen/heren-c/) for instance this is team "Heren C". As you can see in the calendar below there are some home games and some away games. We also have "Heren A", "Heren B", "Junioren", "Cadetten", and so on...

Now, these calendars are all tables and I would like to color (in this example) "Heren C" and make it bold. I want to do this for all our teams, so without actually going through each table and change these text instances.

Just to be sure I will mention that it's a Wordpress site and that each team is a different page, so it's loaded with the same template each time. Maybe that can help for the code.

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**CSS3 Attribute Selectors**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors)

```
a[href*="heren-c"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

the `*=` operator to make an attribute selector match elements that have an attribute which contains the specified value:

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be possible purely in cross browser compliant CSS as there is nothing to hook into. Your best bet is going to be either Javascript or PHP search and replace, search for each term and replace with a `<span class="aclass">term</span>` or similar so you have a hook for the CSS.

PHP would be the more fool proof method but Javascript may be a simpler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is allowed (which could really simplify the job in your case), you could try something like this:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Heren C') {
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    }
});
```

I never used Wordpress, but I guess jQuery must be already loaded...